# Difference in difference with delayed effect

Tags: panel-data, difference-in-difference, lags

Imagine I have a policy intervention where I expect a one-period lag between when the intervention happens and when the intervention's effect shows up in my outcome variable. Something slow to adjust, like the unemployment rate - I expect no effect at t=0.

First there's the traditional no-lag model:

- y = time + treat + time*treat

But to add the lag, what is the difference between these three, and is there a clear right-or-wrong choice:

- y = time + treat + (time*treat) + (time*treat)(t+1)
- y = time + treat + (time*treat)(t+1)
- y = time(t+1) + treat + (time(t+1)*treat)

The first option seems correct only if I expect the treatment has both an immediate and a lagged effect. In this case, that is not the model; we're theoretically confident that there is no contemporaneous effect, and want to impose that upfront.

Answer (score 1):

You can use time dummies instead of a post variable, also interacting them with treated. This will allow the DID effect to vary by time very flexibly. If people/units are treated at different times, you will have to redefine time relative to treatment for each unit.

You can also group time into coarser bins and proceed analogously if you want a more parsimonious model. This will give you two sets of policy variables, one for each regime.

The choice will depend on the substance of the problem. Even if the treatment is an announcement of a policy change down the road, that announcement can alter behavior immediately, so I think it is best to include two policy regimes in the model. You could cook up scenarios where the policy decision is made, but kept secret until it is rolled out, where that zero immediate effect is more credible. That scenario seems rare to me. In fact, I cannot think of a single paper where that was the case. In general, you will probably want to run it multiple ways to check robustness, with the two regime or fully flexible effects version as the baseline case. In fact, if your theory predicts zero effect initially, giving the model the ability to reject that seems like a feather in your cap.

Comment: @stats_studier Did this help?